# Making array with input of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to capture the input of a textarea and converting it to an array but it is reading the whole input as one element and making array of length 1.

```
<html>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<input type="submit" onclick="won()">
<p id="one" style="display: none;"></p>
</html>
```

The js part displays a message of the length of the array.

```
var area = document.getElementById("area");
var lines = area.value.split("\n");
var pa = document.getElementById("one");

function won() {
  pa.style.display = "block";
  pa.innerHTML = lines.length;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve with the whole thing is that. The multi line input is to be converted into an array with each new line being a new element. Then I loop through the array and if even one element doesn't pass a validation function, an exception message is displayed under the texarea.

Can someone kindly help me with this?

Comment: how do you seperate the lines? Are you pressing enter or do you mean the "normal" break when the line is full?

Comment: @MaG. pressing enter

Comment: `<input type="submit">` without a `<form>` doesn't make much sense. The `var ...` lines have to be in the `won()` function because you (most likely) need the content when that function is executed not when the DOM is parsed.

Comment: @Andreas the function is on the button. I've changed the code now. And the variables are getting declared globally so they're still accessible.

Comment: _"And the variables are getting declared globally so they're still accessible."_ - Which makes no sense (...with this example. There might be a reason, but there's almost always a better way then global variables) and is the source of your problem. At least `var lines = area.value.split("\n");` has to be _in_ `won()` to get the current content of the `<textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your snippet, you're grabbing the value onload so it would be empty, it should be in the event where you grab the value. Also avoid inline event triggering, add the event via js.

```js
var area = document.getElementById("area");
var button = document.getElementById("btn-submit");
var one = document.getElementById("one");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // get value
  var lines = area.value.split("\n");

  one.style.display = "block";
  one.innerHTML = lines.length;
})
```

```html
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
<p id="one" style="display: none;"></p>
```

> What I'm trying to achieve with the whole thing is that. The multi
> line input is to be converted into an array with each new line being a
> new element. Then I loop through the array and if even one element
> doesn't pass a validation function, an exception message is displayed
> under the texarea.

```js
const area = document.getElementById("area");
const button = document.getElementById("btn-submit");
const error = document.getElementById("error");
const items = document.getElementById("items");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  // get textarea value, remove emptys
  const lines = area.value.split("\n").filter(Boolean);

  // reset error and items dom
  error.innerHTML = items.innerHTML = ''
  
  // do your validation, could loop or use .some(), .includes()
  if (!lines.length) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Enter at least one item'
  } else if (!lines.includes('cat')) {
    error.innerHTML = 'Entered lines should include at least one cat'
  } else {
    // no errors
    items.innerHTML = `${lines.length} items<br><ul><li>${lines.join('</li><li>')}</li></ul>`
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="items"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Simply put your line `var lines = area.value.split("\n");` under the `won` function like below and you will get your total lines.

**Example**

```
var area = document.getElementById("area");
var pa = document.getElementById("one");

function won() {
  var lines = area.value.split("\n");
  pa.style.display = "block";
  pa.innerHTML = lines.length;
}
```

You can check it here too, https://codepen.io/vadera-abhijeet/pen/yLPxLRY